# samsung toast framework with LG TV webos is giving error

Tags: command-line-interface, television, webos

we are working with toast framework for LG tv `webos` and `Samsung tizen`.   i have done as per the given setting but unable to build the issue and getting a error
when i run following command in cmd

> grunt compile:tv-webos

Error is following one

> Warning: Task "sectv-prepare:tv-webos" not found.

i have already followed official way

https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast

can anybody tell me where to use this

> 'sectv-prepare': {    // task
>         'tv-webos': {    // target
>             dest: 'platforms/tv-webos/www',  // Destination path to create the application project.
>             platformRepos: '../cordova-tv-webos',    // Path to 'sectv-***` cordova platform's repository.
>             scripts: {  // copy the scripts to the application project. : .
>                 'cordova.js': '../cordova-js/pkg/cordova-tv-webos.js',
>                 'toast.js': '../cordova-plugin-toast/platform_www/tv-webos/toast.js'
>             }
>         }

---

**** i used this in gruntfile.js of project as per official documentation but still same issue

now after few changes i am finding this error

> Cannot find module './packager/tv-webos' Use --force to continue.

AFTER doing everything according to docs. i move on but now found new error

*followed docs from start again but now got new issue

> Fatal error: ares-package ERR! * ares-package: ERROR: 'E:\TV' has no meta files such as appinfo.json